# XOR of two sets of disjoint intervals

Tags: python, list

I have two sets of disjoint intervals and I want to find the XOR of them, e.g. the intervals that include in only one of the sets.

For example:

```
set1 = [[0, 0.2], [0.4, 0.6], [0.8, 1]]
set2 = [[0, 0.21], [0.42, 0.6], [0.8, 1]]
```

and the desired results is:

```
XOR_set = [[0.2,0.21], [0.4,0.42]]
```

I trying with finding the intersection with the code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178427/given-2-disjoint-sets-of-intervals-find-the-intersections/178432#178432). But didn't succeed from there.

I will be glad to any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
set1 = [[0, 0.2], [0.4, 0.6], [0.8, 1]]
set2 = [[0, 0.21], [0.42, 0.6], [0.8, 1]]

[list(set(a) ^ set(b))  for a, b in zip(set1, set2) if a != b]
```

Comment: thanks, but it isn't my original meaning. I asked the new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61043853/complement-between-two-sets-of-intervals-in-python)