# complement between two sets of intervals in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two sets of disjoint intervals and I want to find the intervals that contained in only one of the sets (this is kind of symmetric complement of the intervals in the sets).

For example 1:

```
set1 = [[0, 2], [4, 10]]
set2 = [[1,2], [4, 10]]
```

and the desired results is:

```
sub_intervals_in_one_set_only = [[0,1]]
```

`[[0,1]]` containd in the  only in set1 (in [0,2]) but not contained in any interval in set2.

For example2:

```
set1 = [[0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.6], [0.65, 0.66], [0.8, 1]]
set2 = [[0, 0.21], [0.42, 0.6], [0.8, 1]]
```

and the desired results is:

```
sub_intervals_in_one_set_only = [[0,0.1],[0.2,0.21], [0.4,0.42], [0.65, 0.66]]
```

`[0,0.1], [0.2,0.21]` included only in set2, `[0.4,0.42], [0.65, 0.66]` included only in set1.

I trying with finding the intersection with the code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178427/given-2-disjoint-sets-of-intervals-find-the-intersections/178432#178432). But didn't succeed from there.

I will be glad to any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Is `[0,0.1]` in any of the sets?

Comment: the order of the elements in the sublists for the desired output is impp ?

Comment: Can you explain what *"sub-intervals that included in only one of the sets"* means? I can't make anything from desired result.

Comment: [0,0.1] is an interval. it's included in the interval [0,0.21] that included in set2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor
from itertools import chain


set1 = [[0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.6], [0.65, 0.66], [0.8, 1]]
set2 = [[0, 0.21], [0.42, 0.6], [0.8, 1]]

l = sorted((reduce(xor, map(set, chain(set1 , set2)))))
[l[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]
```

output:

```
[[0, 0.1], [0.2, 0.21], [0.4, 0.42], [0.65, 0.66]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the `portion` library I developed (https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion). It's available on PyPI as well (`pip install portion`).

```
import portion as P

set1 = [[0, 2], [4, 10]]
set2 = [[1,2], [4, 10]]

i1 = P.Interval(*[P.closed(x, y) for x, y in set1])
i2 = P.Interval(*[P.closed(x, y) for x, y in set2])

# Symmetric difference
print((i1 - i2) | (i2 - i1))
```

... displays `[0,1)`, notice the right `)` since `1` is not in the complement (it is in `set2`).

For the second example:

```
set1 = [[0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.6], [0.65, 0.66], [0.8, 1]]
set2 = [[0, 0.21], [0.42, 0.6], [0.8, 1]]

i1 = P.Interval(*[P.closed(x, y) for x, y in set1])
i2 = P.Interval(*[P.closed(x, y) for x, y in set2])

# Symmetric difference
print((i1 - i2) | (i2 - i1))
```

... displays `[0,0.1) | (0.2,0.21] | [0.4,0.42) | [0.65,0.66]`. Notice again that some intervals are semi-open.